# Azure AD application permission with scopping

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365

As per the below article, we can scope AzureAD Graph API permission from Exchange online.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

We've assigned the following permission in AzureAD. However Calendars.ReadWrite "Application permission" is scoped for only a room mailbox account. So that application will only able to read/write room mailbox calendar.

[image]

Could someone please answer the below question?

I am not a member of the Scoping group and if I use the application token, will I be able to access my Calendar (Please note that calendars.ReadWrite.Shared delegated permission already granted in AzureAD)

Answer (score 1):

No, in the case that you use application token, and you are not in the scoping group, the application won't be able to access your Calendar.

`calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` delegated permission doesn't take effect on client credential flow. It only takes effect when you use [user token (auth code flow)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) rather than [application token (client credential flow)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).

Comment: Can I use a user token when requesting delegated permission? Is there any sample Graph API code that I can use?

Comment: @POSHGuy Yes. You could use user token with delegated permission to access your calendar. See samples here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials. For example, if you need a ASP.NET core sample, find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core

Comment: @POSHGuy Any updates? If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: I tested using the user token. But I got an error saying that I am not part of the role group.. Meaning I should be a member of the scoping group to get token..

Comment: @POSHGuy Sorry maybe I have a misunderstanding with your question "Can I use a user token when requesting delegated permission?". Although you are using user token, you still need to follow the Application Access Policy.